# would I need an adfs-proxy for external domain name different than domain name used for internal dns?

Tags: adfs

we have an internal domain name used for ad, foo.local.
we are currently setting up an application which uses adfs for authentication, and wish to use app.foo.com and adfs.foo.com for our adfs.

if I setup my adfs instance on adfs.foo.local, and create a second web-application on the adfs.foo.local machine that will use a ssl certificate with a cn=adfs.foo.com, will this be sufficient, or do I need an adfs proxy to pull this off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name for ADFS has to be the same both internally and externally. This is a function of how the app interacts with ADFS.

The proxy enables easy external access with a different authentication mechanism (e.g. forms based) than internally (e.g. Windows Integrated Auth). If you want to use the same AuthN mechanism internally and externally, you could easily just NAT the ADFS servers directly.